# Wrong number of argument or invalid property assignment collection adding

Tags: vba, excel

I've been getting a

> wrong number of argument or invalid property assignment collection

error for a long time now, but can't figure out what's wrong. I have a class and a `Collection` inside that class and a `Sub` to add values to that collection.

```
Private sumLosses As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize() 
    Set sumLosses = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Get getSumLosses()
    getSumLosses = sumLosses
End Property
```

Inside main module:

```
For Each clientCopy In clientsColl
        clientCopy.getSumLosses.Add 200  'error
        clientCopy.getSumLosses.Add (200) 'error
Next
```

Why does this fail and how do I add the items to a class' collection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sumLosses` is of type `Collection` therefore it is an object and has to be `Set` to another variable/function.

With using `Set` it should work:

```
Public Property Get getSumLosses() As Collection
    Set getSumLosses = sumLosses
End Property
```

Also defining the property `As Collection` might be no bad idea (but this didn't cause the error).

Comment: Thank you. Easy mistake, didn't even notice, thought it's something more.

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare `Public Property Get getSumLosses()` as a **`Collection`** and use `Set` :

```
Private sumLosses As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize() 
    Set sumLosses = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Get getSumLosses() as Collection
    Set getSumLosses = sumLosses
End Property
```

:)